# Is it okay if I ask people to review my cover letter / message?

Tags: discussion

I have been freelancing for 3-4 every now and then. I have done at least 10 freelancing gigs so far. Out of which 1 went horribly wrong (but that was a long time ago). Everything else was a good gig. Some of my old clients still contact me every not and then for a gig. Most of them are really happy.

I have a decent set of skills (Or at least, I think I do :P). But the problem is I have to apply / bid on at-least 50-70 projects to get one. Sometimes I give up for months because there is no response from the other side.

So, I am guessing that it has something to do with my Cover Letter / bidding message. So I was wondering if it would be okay if I can post a cover-letter / bid message that I send to potential clients and have people review it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Thanks for coming to meta to ask before posting. It doesn't seem likely this will work on our site, but since you asked, here are my thoughts below, which include some *possible*, but not guaranteed, ways this *might* work.

## Reviewing is off-topic

Reviewing the cover letter would be off-topic for this site, simply because it wouldn't fit the Q&A format that is part of all Stack Exchange sites. It's also difficult to formulate specific questions about *your* cover letter that don't end up with the community reviewing the whole thing or taking something out of context.

However, there is a way in which you *can* use the platform to seek assistance.  As someone with freelancing experience, you may very well have suspicions as to what might or might not be wrong with your cover letter.

## Specific questions about cover letters could be on-topic

Try to see if you can think of a question about cover letters in general. Mention your target market, a brief paragraph about the type of work you do, and the demographic of the client.  For instance, "What should I include in a cover letter when targeting a client with 20 employees, who is in manufacturing, and who runs a flat, empowerment based organization with little hierarchy?" would be something specific.

If you have a specific question you could ask that could lead to answers which explain why and how, then this *could* work.

I can't promise it will work though. It's possible the post may be put on hold, either by the community or a moderator, until the post is edited to be on-topic. If that happens, it's not a reflection on you, and try to be open to feedback from the community on how you might edit the post to be on-topic. Look at this as an experiment to see what's possible and not possible on our site. Hope this helps.

Comment: perhaps reviewing is something that can be done in a chat room?  Where would one go for peer review?

Comment: @user6035379 - Chat could work for something like this, but the response time may vary since the chat room isn't very active.  There are likely other sites on the Internet that will work better for peer review and with faster feedback loops; however, it's not the primary goal of Stack Exchange Q&A sites to do peer review.

Comment: adding something like peer review would take SE into a tangent I suppose.  and yes, chat doesn't really work for that.  if i come up with an idea i'll meta it.